# Buggy bootstrap 3 navbar dropdowns and collapse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a bootstrap 3 navbar for a site I'm creating for fun. It looks great but I often run into a bug where the dropdowns won't expand or the collapse button won't work. I'm building it in Rails and added the cdn link to bootstrap.min.js at the bottom of my application.html.erb file.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Am I putting it in the wrong place? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your console? Bootstrap requires JQuery, so it might not be working if you haven't included JQuery as well.

---

However, in a Rails app people usually use the gem [`bootstrap-sass`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails) to incorporate Bootstrap-3. This gem allows you to include bootstrap in the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). It's easier to prioritize the order of your assets when they are all kept within the asset pipeline.

I would strongly recommend using the [bootstrap-sass docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails) to include Bootstrap in your asset pipeline rather than including bootstrap via CDN in your html. The documentation has a step-by-step guide that tells you exactly how to include it, and it's also updated for Rails 5.

One of the benefits of Rails is that it allows you to keep your code very organized, so it's good to include Bootstrap in that organization.

---

Helpful Resources:

- [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails)
- [integrating-rails-and-bootstrap](https://launchschool.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1)

**Update**

With the `bootstrap-sass` gem your `application.js` file should look like this (plus any additional javascripts you might have added):

```
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Most importantly, it needs these two lines in this order to work:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I am using the bootstrap-sass gem and bootstrap gem, however if I dont include the script tag the dropdowns and collapses never work. With it added they work most of the time.

Comment: Ok I'm getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. That must be it, but how can I fix it? In my application.js I have //= require jquery

Comment: Are you usuing Rails 5 or 4? I only ask because rails 5.1+ allows you to use the `jquery-rails` gem. It's important that JQuery is required **before** Bootstrap is required (since Bootstrap depends on JQuery).

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.5

Comment: I posted an update. `application.js` should include JQuery before it includes `bootstrap-sprockets` - assuming you are using the `bootstrap-sass` gem. If you are using another gem, you still need to require JQuery before you require Bootstrap. If you want to do a quick and dirty way, you could include a [JQuery CDN script tag](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/) on the line before you include your Bootstrap script tag. But this will keep these JavaScript files separated from the asset pipeline.

Comment: thanks, this removes the errors from the console but the components are still buggy. Do you think there could be anything else im doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard for me to say without seeing the code. I do think that [this guide](https://launchschool.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1) gives a nice walk-through. Once Bootstrap is implemented correctly, it will work nicely in your project.